# Append DOM DIV to jQuery Dynamically created DIV

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I have created a new DIV via JQuery. Now I want to take an existing div and put it into my dynamically created div. My current solution is not working.

```
$(".body").append("<div id='new'></div>", function(){
            $("#old").appendTo("#new");
        });
```

Am I not able to set non dynamic divs to be children of dynamic divs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("<div/>", { id: "new" }).appendTo("body");

$("#old").appendTo("#new");
```

Comment: Note that i assume that you are appending this to the body tag not an element with the class body as you do.

Answer (score 0):

You're not referencing the 'new' div properly. I suggest removing the hash from the actual id and then doing this:

```
$("body").append("<div id='new'></div>");
$("#old").appendTo( $("#new") );
```

You can leave the hash there if you'd like, but, unless you're using HTML5, id's cannot begin with special characters.

EDIT: You shouldn't have to use the callback and you need to eliminate the '.' from the 'body' as it is not a class unless you have created one. http://jsfiddle.net/ZDFg4/

Comment: Thank you for the help. Updated accordingly still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [.append( content [, content ] )](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content)

```
$(".body").append("<div id='new'></div>", function(){
    $("#old").appendTo( $("#new") );
});
```

so content gets append to no function is called.
<kbd>See [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/buyJr/)</kbd>

---

You can use [.append( function(index, html) )](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html)

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/buyJr/1/)</kbd>

```
$(".body").append(function () {
    return $("<div/>", {
        id: "new"
    }).append($("#old"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly are you intentionally using .body  or you want to append to just

Secondly you are using id="#new" where it should be just id="new"

Third, read .append() documentation on how to use it.

<s>Fourth, you'll need .html()</s>

now try this.

```
$("body").append("<div id='new'></div>");
$("#new").append($('#old'));
```

Comment: You don't need the html();

Comment: I assumed he wanted to copy the div not move.